# ctags: can you ignore matching tags for a specific file extension?

Tags: autocmd, ctags

small background:

- I have a code base with multiple languages: C, C++, Python, Sh, Makefile, Perl.
- I configure my ctags generation right now to just do: C,C++,Python,Sh.
- I point `vim` at the ctags tag file located at `~/tags` (right now i only have one ctags tag file)

When I am editing a C++ file with extension *.cc, I hit <kbd>ctrl+]</kbd> to jump into the tag `dummy_function_name` and I get 10 matches and 9 out of 10 matches are for python files.

### Can you ignore matching tags for a specific file extension (in this case python files)? if yes, how?

Comment: This might be possible using the `tagfunc` feature.

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: I'm not the best at `ctags` but here is one solution I came up with on my own.)

### Solution:

- for each language generate one `ctags` tag file
- for each language tag file create a new `vim` autocommand that sets the tag file to the associated language tag file based on the file extension

Notes:

This solution would required making your ctags generation more complex (instead of one tag file there are N tag files for N languages). In this example, you would one 3 tag files (one for C/C++, one for Python, one for Sh). Then your `vim` config would need to be more complex with N autocommands for the N tag files.

Comment: Added to .vimrc `autocmd BufEnter,BufNew *.cc,*.hh set tags=/data/donn/ctags_cpp`